# How to upload to Gridfs without express in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

I am looking for a way to upload a pdf to gridfs, but I don't want to use Express. I want to upload a pdf that is created on the backend and simply upload it into gridfs. By this I mean I want to send the file directly to the database because the file is already created.

I've seen many articles (ex: https://hevodata.com/learn/mongoose-gridfs/) that describe using an Express endpoint to upload the file like this:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

This is not what I want. I want to send an *already created* pdf file to gridfs so that I can store it in my database. Does anyone know of a way to do this?